# Calculating an index from a combination of indexes

Tags: c#

I have a 2D list that might look something like this:

```
List<List<object>> myCategories;
```

Now each inner list is a list of options in a category. It's a jagged collection, so there might be `2` options in the first list and `4` in the second.

Now I'm transforming that into rows for each combination of categories so, in my example, I'd expect to end up with `2 * 4 = 8` rows in total. Which would be arranged like so:

```
Row | Cat 0    | Cat 1
 0  | Item 0_0 | Item 1_0
 1  | Item 0_0 | Item 1_1
 2  | Item 0_0 | Item 1_2
 3  | Item 0_0 | Item 1_3
 4  | Item 0_1 | Item 1_0
 5  | Item 0_1 | Item 1_1
 6  | Item 0_1 | Item 1_2
 7  | Item 0_1 | Item 1_3
```

Now what I'm struggling with is, given an array of indexes into each category, say `[1,2]`, the row I need would be `6` because that's where I have item `1` from category `0` and item `2` from category `1`.

I had something like this (where `idx` is a `List<int>` with my indexes):

```
var rowIdx = idx.Select((v, i) => new { v, i }).Aggregate(0, (c, n) =>
{
    c += n.v * Math.Max(1, myCategories.Skip(n.i + 1).Sum(a => a.Count));
    return c;
});
```

Which works great with 1 or 2 categories, but falls apart once you hit three categories. For example, if you have `4`,`1` and `1` as the `Count` of each category, and you are looking for the row corresponding to item `1` in category `0` (and obviously `0` and `0` in the other two, because there is only one choice), you end up with an index of `2` instead of `1`.

Here's a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/n1J1Qj):

```
var categories = new List<List<object>>()
{
    new List<object>(){ null, null },
    new List<object>(){ null, null, null, null }
};

var idx = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };

var rowIdx = CalcIndex(categories,idx);

Console.WriteLine(rowIdx);      // outputs 6 as expected

categories = new List<List<object>>()
{
    new List<object>() { null, null, null, null },
    new List<object>() { null },
    new List<object>() { null }
};

idx = new List<int>() { 2, 0, 0 };

rowIdx = CalcIndex(categories,idx);

Console.WriteLine(rowIdx);      // should give 2, but gives 4 instead.

public static int CalcIndex(List<List<object>> categories, List<int> idx) 
{
    return idx.Select((v, i) => new { v, i }).Aggregate(0, (c, n) =>
    {
        c += n.v * Math.Max(1, categories.Skip(n.i + 1).Sum(a => a.Count));
        return c;
    });
}
```

Comment: Would a Dictionary work better in this case, or an actual class? I'm curious why everything is just essentially an array.

Comment: How about improving the question and posting a compilable sample with an expected output.

Comment: @EZI: I thought my table pretty much explained the expected output. So for example, with the pair `[1,2]` and the lengths of each category of `[2,4]`, I'd expect `6`. You can read any other ones off the table.

Comment: @MattBurland But to test my answer I have to prepare a test case. I think this should be in the question. See [this](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @MattBurland I saw it. Very good now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you know the lower (usually 0) and upper (usually n-1) bounds of each index range, you can call the correct "row" for an almost infinite amount of inidices:

sample:  4D list with sizes 2, 4, 6, 8.
GetRow (1,2,3,4) -> 1×4×6×8 + 2×6×8 + 3×8 + 4 (row numbering starting at 0)

Comment: Damn. I knew I'd over complicated things. I'd convinced myself that wasn't right, but I think it is.

Comment: I was about to make the same mistake when writing the answer. When I added the sample to help myself, I saw how easy it actually is.  ;-)